# line 21: syntax error near unexpected token `done', and then: line 21: ` done'

Tags: bash

I got the mentioned errors in this bash script:

```
line 21: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
line 21: ` done'
```

I looked for empty loops like mentioned here in other questions, and I see nothing. Any idea why?

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -a line; do
    :
    for word in ${array[*]}; do
        let last_index=${#arr[*]}-1
        bool=false
        if [[ $word != [1-9]* && bool==true ]]; then
            echo -n $word
        else if [[ $word != [1-9]* && bool==false ]]; then
                bool=false
                echo -n "_$word"
        else if [[ $word == ${array[last_index]} ]]; then
                date=${word//./ }
                for element in $date; do
                    element=${element/0}
                done
                echo " $date"
        else echo -n " $word "
        fi
    done
done
```

Answer (score 3):

You've only got one `fi`, where you have three `if` statements, so the `done` isn't expected.  You need to use `elif` rather than `else if`.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -a line; do
    :
    for word in ${array[*]}; do
        let last_index=${#arr[*]}-1
        bool=false
        if [[ $word != [1-9]* && bool==true ]]; then
            echo -n $word
        elif [[ $word != [1-9]* && bool==false ]]; then
            bool=false
            echo -n "_$word"
        elif [[ $word == ${array[last_index]} ]]; then
            date=${word//./ }
            for element in $date; do
                element=${element/0}
            done
            echo " $date"
        else echo -n " $word "
        fi
    done
done
```

Or you need to indent the second and third `if` statements more and add the missing `fi` markers.

Incidentally, the colon command is harmless but does nothing useful in this script.